# Calculating the pressure between a housing and a shaft in an interference fit

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, contact-mechanics

I'm trying to calculate the pressure between a journal/shaft and a housing bore in a case of interference fit.

Considere a 2D axisymmetric (effectively 1D) journal bearing with interference fit:

> [image]

Where $D_1 > D_2$ and after fitting we should have $D_1>D_4>D_2$ and I think also $D_5>D_3$. Writing the continuum equation of equilibrium for the 1D problem:

$$ \frac{d \sigma_r}{d r} +\frac{\sigma_r-\sigma_\theta}{r}=0 \tag{1}$$

and the elements of the strain tensor can be calculated from radial displacement:

$$\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\epsilon_r=\frac{d u}{d r}\\
\epsilon_\theta=\frac{u}{r}
\end{matrix}
\right. \tag{2}$$

where $u$ is the radial displacement. And the Hooke's law including the Poisson's ratio for stress-strain tensors :

$$ 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\sigma_r=\frac{\lambda}{\nu}\left( \left(1-\nu  \right)\epsilon_r +\nu \epsilon_\theta \right)\\
\sigma_\theta=\frac{\lambda}{\nu}\left( \left(1-\nu  \right)\epsilon_\theta +\nu \epsilon_r \right)
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{3}$$

Where $\lambda=\frac{\nu E}{\left(\nu+1 \right)\left(1-2 \nu \right)}$ is the Lame’s elastic constant. Combining 1, 2 and 3 yields:

$$ u_{rr}+\frac{u_r}{r}-\frac{u}{r^2}=0 \tag{4}$$

Which is a simple second order Cauchy-Euler ODE and has an analytic solution of:

$$u=c_1 r +\frac{c_2}{r}\tag{5}$$

The issue is that this solution is singular at $r=0$, whereas based on the boundary condition we should have $u=0$ there. This doesn't make sense. I'm probably making some mistakes. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

**P.S.1.** The final goal is to answer my other question over [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380917/what-is-the-relation-between-friction-clearance-tolerance-roughness-and-mechan).

**P.S.2.** The assumption of $c_2=0$ also does not work. stress can't be constant.

**P.S.3.** I borrowed the equation 3 from [this lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-314j-structural-mechanics-in-nuclear-power-technology-fall-2006/readings/elsticty_thry.pdf) of ["Structural Mechanics in Nuclear Power Technology" MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-314j-structural-mechanics-in-nuclear-power-technology-fall-2006/) course. But it doesn't makes sense because it is exactly the same as the Cartesian one.

Comment: You are assuming plane strain, correct?  Are you assuming separate displacement relationships for the two regions, correct?

Comment: @ChesterMiller If I understood you correctly you are asking if I'm assuming the displacement of the two is equal at the contact point, which the answer is no. only the radial stress is equal there.

Comment: OK.  That is correct.  Are you assuming that the strain in the z direction is zero?

Comment: @ChesterMiller That's the assumption I have not considered and That probably will change both my question and answer below. depending on either I consider $\epsilon_z=0$ or $\sigma_z=0$ there will be different results. The former is basically a planar problem.

Comment: In my judgment, zero axial strain is more realistic.

Comment: @ChesterMiller true. I totally agree. I will do the calculations and if they are different than what I wrote below I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this Lecture notes](http://courses.washington.edu/me354a/Thick%20Walled%20Cylinders.pdf) from ["Mechanics of Materials Laboratory, University of Washington"](http://courses.washington.edu/me354a/) and also considering the planar version of equations 2 and 3 as:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\sigma_r=\frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\left( u_r +\nu \frac{u}{r} \right)\\
\sigma_\theta= \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\left( \nu u_r +\frac{u}{r} \right)
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{6}$$

Combining with 5:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\sigma_r=\frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\left( c_1 \left( 1+\nu \right) +c_2 \left( \frac{1-\nu}{r^2} \right) \right)\\
\sigma_\theta= \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\left( c_1 \left( 1+\nu \right) -c_2 \left( \frac{1-\nu}{r^2} \right) \right)
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{7}$$

If we use the hypothetical cylinder proposed in the reference with the pressure boundary conditions of $P_o$ at $r_o$ and $P_i$ at $r_i$ then:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
c_1=\frac{1-\nu}{E}\left(
\frac{r_i^2 P_i -r_o^2 P_o}{r_o^2-r_i^2}
\right)\\
c_2=\frac{1-\nu}{E}\left(
\frac{r_i^2 r_o^2 \left( P_i - P_o\right)}{r_o^2-r_i^2}
\right)
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{8}
$$

Which if applied for our problem implies:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
c_{11}=\frac{1-\nu_1}{E_1}P=A_1 P\\
c_{21}=0
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{9}
$$

For the shaft and

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
c_{12}=\frac{1-\nu_2}{E_2}\left(
\frac{r_2^2 }{r_3^2-r_2^2}
\right)P=A_2 P\\
c_{22}=\frac{1-\nu_2}{E_2}\left(
\frac{r_2^2 r_3^2  }{r_3^2-r_2^2}
\right)P=A_3P
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{10}
$$

For the housing, Where in both 9 and 10 $P$ is the contact pressure between the two. Also considering another boundary condition

$$r_2 +\delta_2 =r_1-\delta_1=r_4 \tag{11}$$

Where $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are the displacements of journal and housing at contact point respectively. Which can be calculated as:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\delta_1=c_{11}r_1\\
\delta_2=c_{12}r_2+\frac{c_{22}}{r_2}
\end{matrix}
\right.
\tag{12}
$$

Now if we combine equations 9, 10, 11 and 12 we can calculate interference pressure as:

$$P=\frac{r_1-r_2}{A_1 r_1 +A_2 r_2 +\frac{A_3}{r_2}} \tag{13}$$

This gives the solution I was looking for but the paradox I raised above is still there. Displacement at the center must be zero.

Comment: @ChesterMiller  here I think I have achieved the parameter I was looking for (if not making any silly mistakes as always)  but still the paradox creeps my mind!

Comment: For the shaft, if u is proportional to r, it means that the radial stress is equal to the hoop stress, and the radial stress is constant.  So the state of stress is homogeneous and transversely isotropic in the shaft.

Comment: @ChesterMiller true. And this I think is the key to resolving the paradox above. basically if the internal diameter of a thick cylinder is zero then the radial pressure is constant and displacement is of course zero at the center.

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: Great question and an answer, but maybe this should be transferred over to Engineering Stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If I may add, I have  another expression for calculating the maximal pressure that occurs between the housing and a shaft in an interference fit.

It is derived using Hooke's law and von Mises criterion. I will not be going through the whole derivation because it is quite involved. I will just provide the final expression.

It is as follows:

$$p=\xi_{max}\frac{E_o}{K}=\frac{|O_{max}|}{D_F}\frac{E_o}{K}$$

where $p$ is the maximal pressure, $\xi_{max}$ is the maximal relative overlap, $E_o$ is the Young's modulus of the housing material, $D_F$ is the fit diameter and $O_{max}$ is the maximal overlap.

$K$ is defined as:

$$K=\frac{E_o}{E_i}\left(\frac{1+Q_i^2}{1-Q_i^2}-\mu_i\right)+\frac{1+Q_o^2}{1-Q_o^2}+\mu_o$$

Where: $E_i$ is the Young's modulus of the shaft material and $\mu_i$ and $\mu_o$ are the Poisson's ratios of the shaft and housing respectively.

Also $Q_i$ and $Q_o$ are defined as:

$$Q_i=\frac{D_i}{D_F}$$

$$Q_o=\frac{D_o}{D_F}$$

where $D_i$ and $D_u$ are the diameters of the shaft and the housing, respectively.

So the final expression looks as:

$$p=\frac{|O_{max}|}{D_F}\frac{E_o}{\frac{E_o}{E_i}\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{D_i}{D_F}\right)^2}{1-\left(\frac{D_i}{D_F}\right)^2}-\mu_i\right)+\frac{1+\left(\frac{D_o}{D_F}\right)^2}{1-\left(\frac{D_o}{D_F}\right)^2}+\mu_o}$$